# Why unity crashes when using shell32 in unity3d?

Tags: unity

I'm using shell 32 to get some file descriptions. It works perfect in Visual Studio 2010, but when it comes inside unity3d it crashes.

The code is:

```
using Shell32;

ShellClass shell = new ShellClass();
Folder objFolder = shell.NameSpace(path);

string fileTitle = objFolder.GetDetailsOf(objFolder.Items().item(0),21); //Crash on this line
```

I appreciate your help.

Comment: Sorry about the tags, I couldn't add more, but they are actually, "Shell32", "Crash", "Error"

Comment: Do you *have* to use Shell32? It won't of course work on Mac, iOS, Android, or the WebPlayer.

Comment: What is column 21?

Comment: I'm writing a plugin, it won't need to be there for compile. just using inside the editor... 21 will return the title

Comment: Well, Shell32 is Windows system-specific API, I'm surprised in even compiles in Unity. What exactly are you trying to do? Maybe it can be done with System.IO?

Comment: @Nevermind See, when you right-click a file>properties>details tab> under description section you have some information that can not be accessed other way. Am i right? do you know a better way to extract those data?

Comment: Try using System.Diagnosics.FileVersionInfo (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/91sft6af.aspx)

Comment: Tried that already, it returns empty string for most members of the class.

Answer (score 3):

Using Shell32 isn't portable.

Have you tried using the .net equivalents?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesysteminfo.aspx

Comment: Thanks Tetrad, I looked into it. It won't give access to details tab.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, use the System.IO; namespace

there you have multiple interesting methods like

File.Exists(...)
Directory.Exists( ...)
Path.GetDirectoryName(...)
Path.Combine(path, filename)
Path.GetFileNameOnly(...)

( note: the method I wrote are not exactly correctly named, but you get the picture) :)

Cheers
T.